# Map array and include items according to ID using MAP and FILTER

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

The first has some issues, eg:

**Questions** array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Questão 1:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Questão 2:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "Questão 3:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    }
]
```

And the second has the options of choices for the questions above:

**Options** array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 4
    }
]
```

I need to create a new array by joining these two as follows: Comparing the question ID with the option id and including the options within the question array.

Eg.

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Questão 1:',
    essay_question: false,
    value: '2.00',
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        option: 'Opção A',
        correct: false,
        question_id: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        option: 'Opção B',
        correct: true,
        question_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
const questions = question.map((q) => {
  if (options.filter((opt) => opt.question_id === q.id))
    return { ...q.dataValues, options: opt.dataValues };
  return { ...q.dataValues, options: null };
})
```

The map and filter worked, the problem is time to put the options array found inside the questions array. I'm getting the error: "'opt' is not defined."

Comment: `opt` is out of scope in `opt.dataValues`.

Comment: also, what are dataValues? i do not see this in original data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```js
if (options.filter((opt) => opt.question_id === q.id))
```

The `opt` variable only exists within the scope of the filter function:

```js
(opt) => opt.question_id === q.id
```

So when you get to your return, `opt` no longer exists:

```js
return { ...q.dataValues, options: opt.dataValues };
```

---

You could create a merged question/options object using map and filter:

```js
const merged = questions.map(
  q => ({
    ...q, // include the question properties
    options: [
      // copy the options with matching question_id
      ...options.filter(({question_id}) => question_id === q.id)
    ]
  })
);
```

```js
const questions = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Questão 1:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Questão 2:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "Questão 3:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    }
];

const options = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 4
    }
];

const merged = questions.map(
  q => ({...q, options: [...options.filter(({question_id}) => question_id === q.id)] })
);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could collect the options first, grouped by questions and map new objects with options.

This approach avoids to iterate options over and over for finding items with the wanted `question_id`.

```js
const
    questions = [{ id: 2, question: "Questão 1:", essay_question: false, value: 2 }, { id: 3, question: "Questão 2:", essay_question: false, value: 1 }, { id: 4, question: "Questão 3:", essay_question: false, value: 1 }],
    options = [{ id: 1, option: "Opção A", correct: false, question_id: 2 }, { id: 4, option: "Opção B", correct: true, question_id: 2 }, { id: 6, option: "Opção A", correct: false, question_id: 3 }, { id: 7, option: "Opção B", correct: true, question_id: 3 }, { id: 9, option: "Opção A", correct: false, question_id: 4 }, { id: 12, option: "Opção B", correct: true, question_id: 4 }],
    optionsByQuestions = options.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.question_id] ??= []).push(o), r), {}),
    result = questions.map(o => ({ ...o, options: optionsByQuestions[o.id] || [] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do it:

```
questions.forEach(q => {
  q.options = options.filter( opt => q.id == opt.question_id);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like:

```
const questions = question.map((q) => {
  const opt = options.filter((opt) => opt.question_id === q.id)
  return opt ? ({ ...q.dataValues, options: opt.dataValues }) : ({ ...q.dataValues, options: null });
})
```